# jquery group every 3rd div

Tags: jquery, html, css-selectors, jquery-selectors, grouping

I have the following structure, one outer div (#results) and about 20 divs with the class event. I want to group every 3 events and wrap a div called outer around them,

```
<div id="result">

    <div class="event">
        <div class="date">8 April</div> 
            <div class="eventname">my title</div>
            <div class="link">my link goes here</div>
    </div>

// lots more events here
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
while ($('#result > .event').length > 0) {
    $('#result > .event:lt(3)').wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>')
}​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rxxjp/

Comment: Clever use of direct-child - I like it. There's probably a dozen ways to approach this same problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one approach: http://jsfiddle.net/vM9KM/4/

```
$('#result').children('div.event:nth-child(3n+1)').each(function(i,el) {
    $(this).next().andSelf().next().andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="outer">');
});​
```

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 1):

I have used `splice` and `wrapAll` function to group 3 div's and wrap them inside `<div class="wrapper" ></div>`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Mtq84/2/)

```
var events = $('#result .event');

while (events.length >= 3) {
    $(events.splice(0, 3)).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
}

//wrap the remaining < than 3 div inside wrapper
$(events.splice(0, events.length)).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
```